# Testing how well a sequence of observed word game solutions corresponds to expected word frequencies

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, games

Say we have a word game where each round involves finding a unique 5-letter word solution. (Wordle would be an example, for those familiar). For example, we may have a round where the word "magic" is the solution, followed by another with "lowly", etc.

Once a word has been used in a round, it does not reoccur in subsequent rounds - i.e. words are sampled without replacement from some unknown population of 5-letter words.

After N rounds (i.e. after observing N 5-word solutions), we would like to test the hypothesis that the words are being selected from the population of all 5-letter words in the English language, with the probability of a word being chosen determined by its relative frequency in the language.

For example, if we mainly observed rarely used 5-letter words like "ducat" and "karst" in 30 rounds, that would be strong evidence against the hypothesis.

What would be an appropriate way of statistically testing this hypothesis?

This seems like a goodness of fit problem of sorts, however I'm not sure how to account for only one of each item (word) being observed.

Comment: I don't follow one remark: when common words *do* appear early on, doesn't that provide evidence *for* the hypothesis you stated, rather than against it?  This makes me wonder exactly what your hypothesis is.

Comment: Thanks - have edited that particular example to remove the ambiguity of "mainly observed commonly used words" - I'd meant that commonly used words were occurring too frequently, but that wasn't clear.

Comment: That's an interesting point, because to assess whether they are *too* frequent, you would set a *high* threshold on the likelihood rather than the low one I recommended.  This is because "too frequent" is detected by "the likelihoods of the sequences tend to be too close to the maximum possible likelihood." For instance, in my example, very few simulated games had log likelihoods within $4$ of the maximum and about 95% of them had log likelihoods more than $7$ below the maximum.  If you observed a word sequence with, say, a relative log likelihood of $-2,$ it would be suspicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't be possible to test this hypothesis without knowing the relative frequencies in the language.  Let, then, the language consist of a set of words $\Omega$ and suppose $p(\omega)$ is the relative frequency in the language of word $\omega.$  Thus, the sum of the $p(\omega)$ is $1.$

$N$ rounds randomly sampled without replacement according to the distribution $p$ produce a sequence $\mathbf w = (\omega_1, \omega_2, \ldots, \omega_N)$ of distinct words.  Since (1) the likelihood of the sequence $(\omega_1)$ is $p(\omega_1)$ and (2) the likelihood of $\mathbf w$ followed by yet another word $\omega_{N+1}$ is

$$\Pr(\omega_{N+1} \mid \mathbf w)\Pr(\mathbf w) = \left(1-\sum_{i=1}^N p(\omega_i)\right)^{-1}\Pr(\mathbf w),$$

we find recursively that the likelihood of $\mathbf w$ is

> $$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf w) = \prod_{j=1}^N \left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} p(\omega_i)\right)^{-1}p(\omega_j).\tag{*}$$

**The sampling distribution of $\mathcal L$ depends strongly on the word frequencies in the language and on the number of rounds $N.$**  A simulation can estimate quantiles of this distribution.  Any observed sequence of words with a likelihood at or below a sufficiently low quantile can then be considered evidence that selection probability is not proportional to probability in the language.

Simulations with realistic distributions and also with small test sets indicate this threshold can be estimated with reasonable accuracy in samples of size $50$ and quite precisely in samples of size $500.$  This shows that **estimating the threshold is computationally practicable.**

---

For instance, I inspected a database of "English" word frequencies [available on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/english-word-frequency/version/1).  Although it has a third of a million "words," after about the first 100,000 I see mostly nonsense.  I extracted the five-letter words from the first 100,000 rows, finding 11,644 (with their frequencies).  Here is a histogram of the log frequencies.

[image: Histogram of log frequencies ranging from cl. -14 to -4]

Unsurprisingly, a few words ("about," "other," "which,"...) predominate over many rare and obscure words and non-words such as "velas" (a company name), "marea" (Italian and a company name), "vidro" (a [real word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vidro)), *etc.*  Here is a summary:

```
> Omega
        word      count
    1: about 1226734006
    2: other  978481319
    3: which  810514085
    4: their  782849411
    5: there  701170205
   ---                 
11640: macks      99222
11641: isaca      99192
11642: vidro      99158
11643: marea      99140
11644: velas      99134
```

The total count (for all 11644 five-letter words) is 68242256931: this is needed to convert these counts into relative frequencies if you wish to verify my calculations below.

The maximum possible log likelihood $\Lambda_0$ is easy to calculate from the first $N$ words in the dictionary.  (It is $-21.58917$ in for $N=5,$ corresponding to the sequence "about," "other," "which," "their," "there.")  Of interest, then, is the distribution of log likelihoods *relative to this maximum* under the null hypothesis of probability sampling according to the dictionary. Here are the relative log likelihoods found in a random sample of $500$ of these games of $N=5$ rounds.

[image: Histogram of log relative likelihood]

(Those of you who were hoping this might be related to a chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom are obviously out of luck.  The shape of this distribution depends *very much* on the dictionary, the frequencies, and the number of rounds.)

The vertical red line marks the 5th percentile of this distribution.  In repeated sampling, this percentile stays around $-20$ to $-20.5.$  It tends to be close to $-20$ even in samples of just $50$ games.  A sequence of rounds with a smaller relative log likelihood is likely to occur less than (approximately) 5% of the time.

**As an example of using this method,** suppose $5$ rounds produced the sequence "stems," "river," "trade," "about," and "lotto."  These words have counts of 3336905, 78843808, 110086585, 1226734006, and 3112797, respectively, in the database.  Formula $(*)$ gives a likelihood of $\mathcal L = 7.662593\times 10^{-17}.$  Relative to the maximum likelihood of $\mathcal L_0 = 4.206725\ldots \times 10^{-10},$ its logarithm is $-21.6.$  Because this is less than $-20.5,$ this would be modest evidence, at a 100% - 5% = 95% confidence level, that the selection was *not* proportional to frequency.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer and example